Are professional cameras better when it comes to knowing how others see you?
If one wants to know what they look like in the perception of people, then mirror won't be an accurate representation as it is a flipped image. Smartphone cameras do not flip, yet they can distort image due to small focal lengths. What about the cameras used in professional studios? Can they provide a better approximation of what one looks like?

As a side note: You can scan yourself as 3D model in a 3d scanner and have that printed. I did it myself, its fun ;)

"Smart phone cameras do not flip". My Samsung selfie preview is a mirror image, and there is a settings option to flip the picture taken.

The only factor is distance.
With a very long selfie stick (or asking someone to take picture of you from far away), your phone will have the same perspective as a pro camera and a long lens (but the picture will have less pixels).

It's not the cameras per se. It's that a bigger sensor is used with longer lenses.  Lenses with longer physical focal lengths and bigger working distances in studios that let you avoid perspective distortion (and lens barrel distortion) vs. a smartphone camera.
Perspective distortion happens with very short lenses used in very close to the subject.
A smartphone camera is typically held at arm's length and will probably have a physical focal length in the 4-10mm range (while it may be 24mm equivalent, the crop factor on the smaller sensor can be 4-6x). In a studio, a photographer can use a much longer lens (say, 50mm to 135mm) from farther away, and that won't create the "funhouse mirror" effect of a short lens used close in.
Keystoning may also have an effect, and that's more on how the camera is positioned relative to the subject than the camera or lens.

I don't think your answer is totally precise. Focal length does not affect perspective; this is well established. Perspective is controlled by distance to the subject. A smartphone held at arm's length is no worse than a "professional" camera held at arm's length.

@osullic, except that very wide angle lenses are also more prone to barrel distortion, and with phone cameras we're talking very very short lenses. I agree the majority of the effect is perspective distortion, but you're also assuming a perfect world where the shorter lenses have the same amount of barrel distortion control as longer ones, and you're also not accounting for the extremely short the focal lengths on phone camera lenses.

Whether a lens is "wide-angle" or not is not related to the focal length per se, but the size of the sensor behind it. (Well, it's related to both together, of course.) It's worth also bearing in mind that phone photos are computationally processed heavily - for this reason they could even have less barrel distortion than, say, a DSLR lens.

In terms of perspective there's no difference between a phone camera and a large sensor ILC, but in terms of geometric distortion caused by the lens' projection, there can be a marked difference. It does make me uncomfortable to include both perspective and geometric distortion in the same generalization about using wide angle lenses in close, though, because that often leads many to falsely believe that focal length has anything to do with perspective. Strictly speaking, there's no such thing as perspective distortion, only perspective.

This is actually a complex question.
Strictly in terms of photography, the only factor of relevance is the perspective; distance and angle. Focal length and sensor size do not really contribute other than together determining the composition (what fits within the image). A "normal perspective" is at a distance of approximately 12ft (10-15). This is the primary consideration.
Lenses can contribute lens errors such as pincushion or barrel distortion; but that is a lens specific variable.
The part that makes this a complex question is perception. A short subject distance causes the spatial relationships of things within the scene to appear to expand... i.e. nose big/close and ears small/far. And a long subject distance causes spatial relationships to contract (I really dislike the common use of the terms "distortion" and "compression" here). This happens even when no camera is involved... it's all due to relative sizes/distances. However, our brains correct for it and we don't really perceive it when there in person. Our brains fix a lot of things like that; e.g. white balance/colors. But when we experience those things out of context in an image they stand out and seem odd because our brains do not correct them (i.e. when not experienced in person).
A simple example of the perspective effect is when looking down a street at a row of cars parked along the curb. It is very easy to determine the space between vehicles that are next to you, where you are closer to them and everything seems larger. But it is much harder to accurately determine the space between the vehicles a block away, where everything appears smaller and closer together.
Similarly, familiarity also affects perception. And the more familiar you are the more likely you are going to perceive what you expect rather than what may actually be true. There's a reason why you might not notice someone's new haircut... it's not (necessarily) that you didn't look at them or see them, it's just that you saw what you expected to see, and not what was reality. A very large part of what we perceive and see is "filled in" by our brains based on previous experience/knowledge rather than actual focused/concentrated/considered vision. There are several optical illusions/quirks humans are susceptible to for this (and related) reason(s).
Accurate depiction in an image is due to using a normal perspective (distance/angle)... how that will be perceived is bit more variable.

Andy Warhol said that he air brushed out skin defects etc on hs photos, because when you look at someone you don't focus on that aspect of them.  And I have personal experience with the haircuts.  I once went into work, greeted everyone in person, and then later went out and got a severe haircut.  Later on when conversing in person with those same people they never noticed my new haircut until much later into the conversation, then it was " .. whoa!!!"

@PeterM, next time you kiss someone pay attention to just how huge and disproportionate their nose looks at that distance... it's disturbing.

I'm not telling my wife she has a big nose.  Do you think I'm stupid or something? /s
